# How to delete / update data in firebase real time database (AngularFireDatabase) using angular 8?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I encountered a problem when I tried to develop an angular application with firebase. When I implemented update and delete function, I could not get the key of data.

```
Company : {
  "-M495Tg10..." : {
    "contact" : "123456789",
    "city" : "abc",
    "name" : "alpha"
  },
  "-M058zy15..." : {
    "contact" : "987654321",
    "city" : "cba",
    "name" : "beta"
  }
}
```

List all companies in `template`. If user clicked the update button, it would fire an event to update the specified company name.

```
    <li *ngFor="let company of companies">
        contact: {{ company.contact }}, city: {{ company.city }}, name: {{ company.name }}

        <button (click)="update(company)">Update</button>
        <button (click)="delete(company)">Delete</button>
    </li>
```

In `component.ts` file, I implemented the update / delete function that accept a parameter to be updated / deleted.

```
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  db.list('Company').valueChanges().subscribe(companies => {
      this.companies = companies;
      console.log(this.companies);
    });

  update(company: any): void {
    // How to get "-M495Tg10..."
    let key = ???;

    this.db.object('Company/' + key).update({ name: company.name + ' _ UPDATE the data'});
  }
```

I had tried `company.$key` and `company.$id`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at [this PR](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/pull/1976/files) and [the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#valuechangesidfield-string) the ID is only merged in with `valueChanges` is you specifically request it.

Something like:

```
db.list('Company').valueChanges({ idField: "$id" }).subscribe(companies => {
```

With that, you can then pick up the id in your rendering, and re-use it when it's time to delete the document.

Comment: `AngularFirestore` has `valueChanges({ idField: "$id" })`. But `AngularFireDatabase` only has `valueChanges()`

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that. In that case you'll need to use `snapshotChanged()`: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#snapshotchanges

Comment: There is a `key` in `snapshotChanges().subscribe(company => {})`. It can be used to get the key. Thanks